# How to show that $\mathbb{R} [i]$ is not contained in the center of $\mathbb{H}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions

Prove that $ \{a + bi | a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is
a subring of $\mathbb{H}$ which is a field but is not contained in the center of $\mathbb{H}$
where  $\mathbb{H}$  denote  Hamilton Quaternions

My attempt : **A non-empty subset S of R is a subring if $a, b \in S ⇒ a - b,ab \in S$**

take $R=\mathbb{H}$, $S=\mathbb{R} [i]=\{a + bi | a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$a= a_1 + b_1 i , b= a_2 +b_2 i $

now  $a-b = (a_1 -a_2) + (b_1 -b_2)i\in S \tag 1$

$ab= a_1a_2-b_1b_2 + (a_1b_2 + a_2b_1)i \in S \tag2$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$  we can say that $S=\mathbb{R} [i]=\{a + bi | a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is  subring of $\mathbb{H}$

**My doubt** :How to show that $\mathbb{R} [i]$ is not contained in the center of $\mathbb{H}?$

Comment: Prove that ther is $a\in S$ such that for any $z\in \Bbb H$, $az\ne za$

Comment: @TitoEliatron No, that's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of the fact that it is a subring is fine.

And it is not contained in the center of $\Bbb H$ because $i\in\Bbb R[i]$ and $ij=-ji\ne ji$.